Why, when installing my own PyPi package, I get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named...?
When trying to use my own package, that I have uploaded to PyPi, I seem to always get this ModuleNotFoundError when trying to use it.
This is my package structure:
Package structure
Here is my setup.py file:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="bsl_translator",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    description="Open source library to translate BSL signs into text",
    readme="README.md",
    author="Miguel Garcia",
    install_requires=[
        "opencv-python>=4.9.0.80",
        "numpy",
        "mediapipe",
        "tensorflow>=2.15.0.post1",
        "keras>=2.15.0",
        "scikit-learn>=1.4.0",
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
    ],
)


This is the content of my __init__.py file:
from translator_fingerspelling import FingerSpelling
It successfully builds, uploads, downloads and installs when using pip install. And this is the output that I get when I run pip list
Package                      Version
---------------------------- -----------
absl-py                      2.1.0
astunparse                   1.6.3
attrs                        23.2.0
backports.tarfile            1.0.0
bsl_translator               0.0.1
...


The issue is that when I try and use it, like in this example:
from bsl_translator import FingerSpelling

img_path = "./test_image.jpg"

fs = FingerSpelling()

print(fs.translate_sign(img_path))

I get the following error:
    from bsl_translator import FingerSpelling
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bsl_translator'


Any ideas on why is this happening?? Is there an obvious solution that I just cannot see? Any help would be really appreciated!
I have tried using different build tools and package structure, installed it locally and it still does not work.

because there is no module named bsl_translator in the package.

Your src-layout is incorrect. Pay attention to the structure in this tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/. You probably need to move all your Python code in a bsl_translator directory under src, so that you have src/bsl_translator/__init__.py, where bsl_translator is your top-level import package.
